# CMS Page Rules Applied to a Blog Post for Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, css, cms, blog

We have different **CSS settings** for a typical **CMS page** vs. a **Blog post**.

I would like the format and style from **CMS applied to 1 blog post**. What do I need to capture to add this inline for the blog post page?

Comment: Please explain for description to the question